# How to do case insensitive search in StringOperators.valueOf("field1").indexOf(txtSchStr))

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, case-insensitive

I have a springdata mongodb aggregation where I use

```
agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(BrkrBean.class, match(criteria),
      project("productId, "fullName").and(
     StringOperators.valueOf("areas").indexOf(searchString)).as("score"))
```

This works fine, but how can I do case insensitive search for the searchString. There is no option for indexOf() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible directly. You will have to do some kind of workaround by converting both field value and search string to same case.

```
StringOperators.valueOf(StringOperators.valueOf("areas").toLower())
  .indexOf(StringOperators.valueOf(searchString).toLower())
```